# WHERE coulmn.name=null doesn't return rows when left join

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

When I do this selcect:

```
SELECT tabuoj.id, tabuoj.tabuo, montritaj_tabuoj.id, montritaj_tabuoj.id_de_tabuo 
    FROM tabuoj LEFT JOIN montritaj_tabuoj 
    ON (tabuoj.id=montritaj_tabuoj.id_de_tabuo)
```

I get:

```
id | tabuo    | id   | id_de_tabuo | 
 1 | dom      | 2    |     1       | 
 2 | samochód | null |    null     | 
 3 | okno     | 1    |     3       |
```

but if I add where in which I compare id_de_tabuo column to null I dont't get any result.

```
SELECT tabuoj.id, tabuoj.tabuo, montritaj_tabuoj.id, montritaj_tabuoj.id_de_tabuo 
FROM tabuoj LEFT JOIN montritaj_tabuoj 
ON (tabuoj.id=montritaj_tabuoj.id_de_tabuo) 
WHERE montritaj_tabuoj.id_de_tabuo=null
```

If I compare for example 1 like this:

```
SELECT tabuoj.id, tabuoj.tabuo, montritaj_tabuoj.id, montritaj_tabuoj.id_de_tabuo 
FROM tabuoj LEFT JOIN montritaj_tabuoj 
ON (tabuoj.id=montritaj_tabuoj.id_de_tabuo) 
WHERE montritaj_tabuoj.id_de_tabuo=1
```

I get correct:

```
id | tabuo    | id   | id_de_tabuo | 
 1 | dom      | 2    |     1       |
```

But I need rows with null in id_de_tabuo column. What I do wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try with `IS NULL` instead of `= null` like this

```
SELECT tabuoj.id, tabuoj.tabuo, montritaj_tabuoj.id, montritaj_tabuoj.id_de_tabuo 
FROM tabuoj LEFT JOIN montritaj_tabuoj 
ON (tabuoj.id=montritaj_tabuoj.id_de_tabuo) 
WHERE montritaj_tabuoj.id_de_tabuo is null
```

Reason: Actually

`montritaj_tabuoj.id_de_tabuo is null` checks that the value is null. whereas
`montritaj_tabuoj.id_de_tabuo = null` checks that the value is equal to NULL which is never true.

Even *NULL is not equal to NULL*. You can check using this.

```
if(null = null)
  print 'equal'
else
  print 'not equal'
```

it will print `not equal`. Now try this

```
if(null is null)
  print 'equal'
else
  print 'not equal'
```

it will print `equal`.

Answer (score 0):

When you filter on a left joined table in the where clause, the join becomes an inner join.  To solve the problem, filter in the from clause, like this:

```
FROM tabuoj LEFT JOIN montritaj_tabuoj 
ON (tabuoj.id=montritaj_tabuoj.id_de_tabuo)   
and montritaj_tabuoj.id_de_tabuo is null

where clause starts here
```

Answer (score 0):

Try just two simple select like

```
select * where id = null
```

and

```
select * where id != null
```

It's a common misconception about null.
Think null as the english word "whatever" in a opposition to "nothing" and you ill start to understand it better.

As sachim answered use

IS NULL

on your predicates.